VPC to VPC communication with DX gateway
Our AWS account currently hosts VPC A which has a database running under routable subnets.
There is a new requirement to pull the existing data via API call initiated by a on-premise consumer.
The new design components we plan to add are (all under existing AWS account) :

New virtual private gateway connected to an existing DX gateway (owned by other account and connected to DX location via private VIF)
New VPC(VPC B) with routable and non-routable subnets

VPC B is being introduced to ensure no/minimal changes to existing VPC A.
VPC B's CIDR range is being advertised back to on-premise automatically (via BGP peering)
Virtual private gateway is attached to VPC B and would receive the request from DX gateway.
VPC B would have routable subnets for NLB and non-routable subnets to host EKS cluster which needs to  interact with database in VPC A to get data.
On prem --> DX gateway --> VPC B --> VPC A
The questions I have :

Since DX gateway doesn't see the VPC A's CIDR (there is a reason why it can't be done), is this solution feasible ?
If #1 is yes, then what's the best way to connect VPC A and VPC B, per my understanding VPC peering isn't supported in this case, do we need to use transit gateway or something else ?


If there is non-overlapping IP addresses between VPC A, VPC B and On-Premise:

You could use a Transit Gateway to facilitate Transitive Routing between the VPCs, and also provide connectivity back to On-Premise, though you mention you have a Private VIF which is not compatible with a Transit Gateway (via an associated DX Gateway). You will need a Transit VIF.

You could use VPC Peering. This is probably the quickest, cheapest and easiest option. As VPCs are non-transitive by design, you will need to connect both of them to a DX Gateway for On-premise connectivity (if needed).


If there is over-lapping CIDRs:

AWS Private Link. Facilitating Producer/Consumer type patterns via the AWS Backbone and communication is established via VPC Endpoints.

AWS VPC Lattice. Providing service-to-service communication via the AWS Backbone and communication is established via VPC Endpoints.

AWS Private NAT Gateways, though you still need a connectivity method so you would combine this with something like a Transit Gateway, but would need to disable propagation and use static routing.


